Three-body solutions with no syzygies?
Montgomery has shown in his paper The zero angular momentum, three-body problem: All but one solution has syzygies, here (PDF), that all negative-energy, zero-angular-momentum solutions of the three-body problem, apart from the Lagrange one, have syzygies.
He says that for negative energy but non-zero angular momentum the theorem is false.
On the other hand, numerical searches for solutions usually start from a collinear configuration, i.e. a syzygy. That makes it unlikely that a solution will be found with no syzygy.
Are there any known solutions of the three-body problem, apart from the Lagrange one, that have no syzygies?

The source you cite (inaccessible behind a paywall) seems to claim that they can "prove that, with the exception of Lagrange’s solution, every solution to the zero angular momentum, Newtonian three-body problem suffers syzygies." (emphasis mine). Would that be a sufficient answer?

@controlgroup I mean other than Lagrange. I updated the question.

That's exactly what control group just said, the paper seems to claim no solution exists other than Lagrange. This seems to answer your question so you  should explain more about why it doesn't. Also a better link to information on the paper like author(s) and title so perhaps people might find better ways to see the article.

@Triatticus the question is about generic angular momentum, the paper is about zero angular momentum

Ah I see, I didn't see that part, but good that you included more ways to see the paper now. At least now people can read the text and decide how/if they answer.
